Is it safer to use many encryption softwares/algorithms for encrypting a file?
I am considering that there may be two ways to have a crypto broken:

The crypto algorithm may age and become vulnerable by applying advanced cryptanalysis methods, just like what happened with old SHA algorithms.

There may be implementation mistakes that create vulnerability, just like PS3.


It is safer, in the sense that can prevent the security fails beforementioned, to use multiple softwares and algorithms?
For example, since I have the file personalFile.dat, I would do:

Compress the file using 7zip software and 7zip algo with password generating  personalFile.7z.
Compress personalFile.7z with zip software with password, generating personalFile.zip.
Compress personalFile.zip with GPG using ECDSA.
Compress the file using GPG and RSA.
Possible other softwares/algorithms...


Don't forget the combined encryption is only as strong as its weakest link. So the reduction of risk may well be illusory. There was a recent related Q&A here.
So, it is not just the implementation complexity and possible implementation errors that is the problem with this approach.

It makes no sense "is only as strong as its weakest link", to break this crypto file is necessary to break the first layer encryption, then break the second... and break all. Do I am wrong?

this is a general principle. if you already knew which layer was weakest, you'd just not include it in the mix would you? and it could be the outermost layer, a weakness you may well be unaware of. there are also attacks such as meet in the middle which may exploit the weakness in a middle layer

Thanks @kodlu , I've read more carefully the references, and the correct is "cascade is at least as difficult to break as the firrst component cipher" or if the ciphers commute, "a cascade is at least as diffcult to break as the most-difficult-to break component". You is right but it is not clear to me that cascade encryption using diferent softwares may protect against implementations bug since the references deal with a single implementation.

Ueli M. Maurer & James L. Massey in 1993 showed in Cascade Ciphers: The Importance of Being First

single point of failure      ----->   welcome.
This is the crux.  No other field of human endeavour puts all of its eggs into one basket.  Ask an Irish potato farmer or the mosquito laying eggs in my thigh. Given the National Security implications we can see why the NSA champions AES which they may already have broken.   See  NOBUS.

Just for fun, you could write down personalFile.dat on paper using a wooden pencil. We made them billions of years  ago.  And they're pretty resistant to root kits and null pointers.
